# remove() not removing a resized image

Tags: jquery-ui

jQuery says about the .remove() method

> Use .remove() when you want to remove
>   the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to
>   the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated
>   with the elements are removed.

But if you remove() the ui-wrapper around an image that has resizing, that doesn't seem to be the case. The image inside the ui-wrapper is left in the DOM.  See jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/jP6NY/2/.

So what is the proper way to removed an image that has resizing?

```
$(function(){  
   $('#pelican').resizable({handles : 'ne,se,sw,nw', aspectRatio : true});
 });

$('button#removeImg').click(function() {
    $('.ui-wrapper').remove();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: as for the line `$('.ui-wrapper').remove();` i search for an object with class named `ui-wraooer` and in your jsfiddle you don't have any. whay are you trying to do? change what?

Comment: @EliranEfron The class is added afterwards, on load. You can inspect element to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the image and the wrapper that was created during the call to .resizable, use:

```
$('#pelican').remove();
```

To remove just the ability to resize the image, while leaving the image in its resized state, use:

```
$('.ui-wrapper').remove();
```

The reason for this is that jQuery and the jQuery UI widgets do some "tidying up" during the calls to .remove(), and the resizable's destructor, producing the behaviour above.